# "An error has occured" while opening PowerPivot workbook on Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, excel-2010, powerpivot

At the beginning I want to say that I'm newbie in Sharepoint and PowerPivot.
I've created powerPivot workbook and uploaded on Sharepoint PowerPivot Gallery. I also created data refreshing schedule. 
But when I try to open uploaded workbook I get an error:

*An error has occurred.
Please try again later.*

When I check refreshing schedule status, there is "succeeded" but I can't open the workbook.
Does anyone know what is the reason of the issue and how to resolve it?

Thank you in advance.
Konrad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created PowerPivot Gallery Site on Central Administration and I didn't have right for using excel application service on CA. That was the reason, why I couldn't open the workbook.

Answer (score 1):

This can occur when a calculation on one or more pages encounters an error. Try looking at each page, including hidden pages, to see if there are any calculation errors in your pivot tables.